# JSON downloading but not adding to UITable, but no errors?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have an API that loads into my app:

> https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?language=2

I have no errors on the API call and no errors in the table view where I run the get data function. Its worked previously perfectly until now. I havent changed any code.

I assumed the servers would be down for the call, but they arent as you can see.

I am running a print 'request was successful' which is displayed in the debug when running, so its getting the data, however the print(self.exercises) returns an empty array hence no table data...any ideas? Here is the API call

```
open class ApiService: NSObject {

    open func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {

        //loads api filtering by english only
        let requestUrl = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&language=2"

        Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( let data):
                    print("Request was sucessful")
                    completionHandler(data as? NSDictionary, nil)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
                }
        }
        return self
    }
```

Table Function

```
        func getApiData() {

    let _ = apiService.getData() {
        (data, error) in
        if let data = data {
            if let results = data["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for result in results {
                    if let exercise = Exercise(dictionary: result) {
                        self.exercises.append(exercise)
                    }
                }
                self.exercisesTableView.reloadData()
                print(self.exercises)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also using a serialization model if that could interfere?

```
final public class Exercise {
var id: Int
var descrip: String
var name: String
var language: [Int]
var muscles: [Int]
var musclesSecondary: [Int]
var equipment: [Int]

public init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {

    guard
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
        let descrip = dictionary["description"] as? String,
        let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
        let language = dictionary["language"] as? [Int],
        let muscles = dictionary["muscles"] as? [Int],
        let musclesSecondary = dictionary["muscles_secondary"] as? [Int],
        let equipment = dictionary["equipment"] as? [Int]
    else { return nil }

    self.id = id
    self.descrip = descrip
    self.name = name
    self.language = language
    self.muscles = muscles
    self.musclesSecondary = musclesSecondary
    self.equipment = equipment
}
```

Comment: have you set your tableView.datasource property? or are you using a UITableVIewController? is your tableView datasource delegate functions reading the data from self.excercises? there isn't enough info here

Comment: You say that `print(self.exercises)` prints an empty array. Could it be that your creation of `Exercise` elements fails? Try adding a `print` inside `for result in results` and another inside `if let exercise = Exercise(dictionary: result)` to see if those are executed

Comment: @vadian was correct, my mistake, though i was confident this issue occurred before I worked on expanding the serialisation, I must have been mistaken, thank you for the solution, if you want to post it as an answer I can mark it otherwise I will just delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry,

> I havent changed any code

is wrong.

You added the properties `musclesSecondary` and `language` and exactly there is the error: `language` is single `Int` rather than an array.

```
var language: Int
...
let language = dictionary["language"] as? Int,
```